# Replace all special character except one

Tags: java, regex

```
string = str.replaceAll("\\W", " ")
```

This replace all special character by " " (space).

But I try to exclude dash "-" as special character.

This my try:

```
string = str.replaceAll("\\W[^-]", " ")
```

But this not that I expect.

**Q**: how do I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to match all the characters except `\w` and `-` you can use:

```
[^\w-]
```

For example:

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\w-]+", " ")
```

Answer (score 5):

[Qtax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16887618/592139) is probably the simplest in this particular case, since there is a built in complement to `\W`, namely `\w`.  But in general, it's useful to know that Java's regex engine supports "intersections" in character classes with the `&&` operator - you can say

```
[\W&&[^-]]
```

to match a single character that is both a `\W` *and* a `[^-]`, i.e. a non-word character but not also a hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negated character class...

```
string = str.replaceAll("[^\\w-]", " ")
```

`\W` is great for convenience, but when you need to add extra characters to your pool, you need to use a character class with `\w`.

The reason this doesn't work...

```
string = str.replaceAll("\\W[^-]", " ")
```

...is because it's scanning for non-word characters (`[^A-Za-z0-9_]`) followed by *not* a `-` character. For example, `/A` would be matched, but `/-` would not be.