# Android Java - String .replaceAll to replace specific characters (regex)

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to remove some specific "special" characters and replace them with empty string if they show up.
I am currently having a problem with the regex, probably with the Java escaping.  I can't put them all together, it just doesn't work, I tried a lot! T_T

Currently I am doing it one by one which is kinda silly, but for now at least it works, like that :

```
public static String filterSpecialCharacters(String string) {
    string = string.replaceAll("-", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\[", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\]", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\^", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("/", "");
    string = string.replaceAll(",", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("'", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\*", "");
    string = string.replaceAll(":", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\.", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("!", "");
    string = string.replaceAll(">", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("<", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("~", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("@", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("#", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("$", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("%", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\+", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("=", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\?", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("|", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\"", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\)", "");
    string = string.replaceAll("\\(", "");
    return string;
}
```

Those are all the character I need to remove:

```
- [ ] ^ / , ' * : . ! > < ~ @ # $ % + = ? | " \ ) (
```

I am clearly missing something, I can't figure out how to put it all in one line. Help?

Comment: Put inside a character class: `[<>!~@^()....]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887607/replace-all-special-character-except-one

Comment: It looks very much like `string = string.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "")`. See [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): *`\p{Punct}` Punctuation: One of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_\`{|}~`*. However, I see you have a bit fewer symbols defined in your class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code does not work in fact because `.replaceAll("$", "")` replaces an end of string with empty string. To replace a literal `$`, you need to escape it. Same issue is with the pipe symbol removal.

All you need to do is to put the characters you need to replace into a character class and apply the `+` quantifier for better performance, like this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:.!><~@#$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+", "");
```

Note that inside a character class, most "special regex metacharacters"  lose their special status, you only have to escape `[`, `]`, `\`, a hyphen (if it is not at the start/end of the character class), and a `^` (if it is the first symbol in the "positive" character class).

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7qk1Te):

```
String s = "-[]^/,'*:.!><~@#$%+=?|\"\\()TEXT";
s = s.replaceAll("[-\\[\\]^/,'*:.!><~@#$%+=?|\"\\\\()]+", "");
System.out.println(s); // => TEXT
```

Comment: The pipe (`|`) also needed escaping in his original code (but not in yours).

Comment: Yes, added a note on that to the answer.

Comment: I meant to say he *should have* escaped it, but didn't.

Comment: It looks very much like `string = string.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "")`. See [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): *`\p{Punct}` Punctuation: One of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_\`{|}~`*. However, I see you have a bit fewer symbols defined in your class.

Answer (score 6):

**Use these codes**

```
String REGEX = "YOUR_REGEX";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
yourString = m.replaceAll("");
```

**UPDATE :**

Your REGEX looks something like

```
String REGEX = "-|\\[|\\]|\\^|\\/|,|'|\\*|\\:|\\.|!|>|<|\\~|@|#|\\$|%|\\+|=\\?|\\||\\\\|\\\\\\\\|\\)|\\(";
```

**SAPMLE :**

```
String yourString = "#My (name) -is @someth\ing"";
//Use Above codes
Log.d("yourString",yourString);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: first of all thank you for taking your time and trying to help me. appreciate it a lot ! 2ndly, -> String REGEX = "\"[^/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\\\"|!\\[#$-]+\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    string = m.replaceAll("");  - this doesn't work.

Comment: can you post your current string.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using valid regex?

Comment: That's my whole issue, i am almost sure that i am NOT using a valid regex hehe.. my string is "\"[^/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\\\"|!\[#$-]+\""

Comment: Hehe I am asking you for sample String where you want to use regex to replace certain characters. This may be your valid regex `\"[^\/,'*:<>!~@#$%^&()+=?()\\\"|![#$-]+\"`

Comment: @JozeRi I tried creating sample REGEX for you.. Try with this `-|\[|\]|\^|\/|,|'|\*|\:|\.|!|>|<|\~|@|#|\$|%|\+|=\?|\||\\|\\\\|\)|\(`

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I did found this helpful! it's certainly another good way to achieve my desired goal, thanks a lot for your time in providing an answer! appreciate it a lot.