# how to remove special character from string except + in android?

Tags: android

I am fetching number from contact book and sending it to server. i get number like this **(+91)942 80-60 135** but i want result like this **+9428060135**.+ must be first character of string number.

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried out this :-String s = number.replaceAll("\\W", ""); but it replace all special character.but i want + otherwise it's working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all special character except one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887607/replace-all-special-character-except-one)

Comment: number.replaceAll("[^(\\d+)]", "");

Comment: @ShreyanshShah check #A Mathew's comments

Comment: String s  =number.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", "");  @ Aldrin Mathew is near to answer just remove '()' from regex.

Comment: `replaceAll("[()]", "");`

Comment: String s =number.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", "");  this is fine solution but it allowed  + after number .ex:-+9428060135+++, but i want + at first position only.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah `String str_inPut="(+91)942 80-60 135";
       String str_replaceFirst =str_inPut.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", ""); //+919428060135
       String str_outPut = str_replaceFirst.substring(3); //9428060135
       String str_required_op="+"+str_outPut;`

Answer (score 1):

Given your example you want to replace the prefix with a single `+` character. You also want to remove other non-numeric characters from the number string. Here's how you can do that:

```
String number = "(+91)942 80-60 135";
number = "+" + number.replaceAll("\\(\\+\\d+\\)|[^\\d]", "");
```

The regex matches any prefix (left paren followed by a `+` followed by one or more digits, followed by a right paren) *or* any non digit character, and removes them. This is concatenated to a leading `+` as required. This code will also handle `+` characters within the number string, e.g. `+9428060135+++` and `+(+91)9428060135+++`.

If you simply wanted to remove any character that is not a digit nor a `+`, the code would be:

```
String number = "(+91)942 80-60 135";
number = number.replaceAll("[^\\d+]", "");
```

but be aware that this will retain the digits in the prefix, which is not the same as your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replace(oldChar, newChar)`. Use the code below

```
String phone = "(+91)942 80-60 135"; // fetched string
String  trimmedPhone = phone.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("-","").trim();
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

check this. Pass your string to this function or use as per code goes

String inputString = "(+91)942 80-60 135";

```
public void removeSpecialCharacter(String inputString) {

    String replaced = inputString.replaceAll("[(\\-)]", "");
    String finalString = replaced.replaceAll(" ", "");
    Log.e("String Output", " " + replaced + " " + second);
}
```