# Replace all special character except "\" and "."

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have one String in java with special characters like this

```
String string = "Report created with id: [2748], generator:file,
 filename:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\UnitTestEncryption.csv.pgp"
```

I need to modify above String like this

```
"Report created with id 2748 generator file
     filename C \Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\UnitTestEncryption.csv.pgp"
```

In simple language , I need to replace all special character except **backslash** "\" and **full-stop** "."
I have already checked with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887607/replace-all-special-character-except-one)

But it wont work for me, specially for **backslash** ('\').

Comment: What's a special character? You mean anything that is not a letter, a number or a whitespace?

Comment: backslash is a escape sequence in java.

Comment: Also, what won't work? Can you please share the piece of code that is not working?

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- Yes Shashank , Thats why it is creating an issue .

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca , Special characters are like "\.[]{}()<>*+-=?^$|" . in that i need to replace all characters except backslash "\" and and full stop "."

Comment: @Indrajeet4192 see my answer it is simple to understand.

Comment: Use `.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^.\\\\]]+", "")`. If you need to add more exceptions, add them to `[.\\\\]`.

Comment: Got the required answer `"string.replaceAll("[^\\w.\\\\]", " ");"` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add what all is acceptable in below list and remove the remaining characters:

```
 string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\\.\\\\]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to loop through the string and create a new string with all the characters which you require.

```
String original="SOME TEXT";
String newStr="";

for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++){
    char ch=original.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch) || ch=='\\' || ch=='.'){
       newStr+=ch;    
      }else {
       newStr+=" "; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a String with special characters

```
String special = "&^#@$*" //what you think is special char.
```

After that take every char of string and compare with special.

```
String myString;

for(int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++){

    if( special.contains( myString.charAt(i) + "" ) ){

         //TODO

    }
}
```

Comment: There may be thousands of special characters.

Comment: Than you can create a String which contains chars which can pass.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted,but this will be another issue you need to create a string with 54 characters.

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- 64, if we include numbers

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca oops i missed numbers,Sorry

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- I don't care about downvote. I'm here to help people because others help me when I need help.

Comment: @raul1ro I am not blaming you,but i said it for my own safety few days ago i met with a serial downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\.]", " ");
```

Just complete the class with whatever you don't want to be replaced.

You may add - and _ for example with:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\._-]", " ");
```